# Access CFBundleVersionString elsewhere in Info.plist

Tags: ios, xcode, plist

I want to append my CFBundleVersionString to my .ipa file name.

In my app`s Info.plist I tried:

```
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)_$(CFBundleVersionString)</string>
```

But it didn´t work. How can I access these values in my plist?:

[image]

Comment: How do you create the ipa file?

Comment: With `gym`. It takes my EXECUTABLE_NAME, but I dont know how to append the version to it.

Comment: Why do you want append version to IPA file name?

Comment: Cause QA says "I want the version to be in the filename so I know what version I`m installing".

Comment: Why don't you rename the file after creation?

Comment: I have to build 5 different versions of my app and I dont want to do rename it everytime I build it.